# Can the concept of matrices be extended to include 3d tuples (3d arrays)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If so can such a formalism give us extra rich structures, in some way. Or can such systems be essentially shown to be equivalent to 2d matrices, or some other structure on V$ \mathbb{x}$ V ?

Comment: They are so useful they have a name https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor They are very useful in some areas of pure math such  as differential geometry and by extension, in physics (from wkipedia: Tensors are important in physics because they provide a concise mathematical framework for formulating and solving physics problems in areas such as stress, elasticity, fluid mechanics, and general relativity), and in applications they are used heavily in machine learning.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Structures like eigenvalues and so on..

Comment: https://www.soest.hawaii.edu/martel/Courses/GG250/gg250_lab_10_ppt.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article about eigenvectors for tensors: [Tensors and their Eigenvectors](http://www.ams.org/journals/notices/201606/rnoti-p604.pdf). It talks about decomposing tensors into sums of rank 1 tensors, singular value decomposition etc.

Sorry this doesn't qualify as answer and thus should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: Now you have enough reputation.